# Bind Data to Modal on table cell click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datatable

I'm trying to bind KnockoutJS ViewModel to a datatable:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/capiono/0vou6xs0/5/)

```
<table class="table table-sm" id="user">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th width="30%" class="text-uppercase">Email</th>
      <th width="15%" class="text-uppercase">Active</th>
      <th width="2%" class="text-center text-uppercase">Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: users() -->
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.id"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.email"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.isDisabled"></td>
      <td class="text-center" data-bind="toggleClick: $root.showDialog"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When a user click the edit on each row it opens a modal dialog, where the data can be edited.

How do I bind the clicked row data to modal dialog form?

so I can do this:

```
  <div class="modal-body" data-bind="with: User">
    <input data-bind="text: email" />
    <input data-bind="text: isDisabled" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I would replace that toggleClick custom binding with a normal click function on your view-model as you really want to do more than just toggle the dialog. With a click function you can then access the row data that was clicked on, and then use that to set a current/selected user.

```
self.toggleClick = function(data){
    self.showDialog(!self.showDialog());
    self.selectedUser(data);
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0vou6xs0/6/

You can then use a `with` binding like you had using the selected-user.

```
<div class="modal-body" data-bind="with: selectedUser">
    <input data-bind="value: email" />
    <input data-bind="value: isDisabled" />
</div>
```